# Getting MessageContext as null in Axis2 client

Tags: soap, apache-axis

I am calling a web service using Axis2 client stubs. I need to get a handle of MessageContext to read attachments that are being sent by service.
Here is what I am doing:

```
    GetEntityServiceStub stub = new GetEntityServiceStub(endpoint);
    stub.setAttributeValues(v1);
    stub.setAnotherAttribute(v2);
    GetEntityResponse response = stub.getEntity();
    MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.currentMessageContext.get() ;// This returns null
    Attachments attachments=messageContext.attachments;
```

This line always returns null value for messageContext :

```
    MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.currentMessageContext.get() ;
```

Or even if I try this in place of above, I still get messageContext as null:

```
    MessageContext messageContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext() ;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.